# Filters list in custom module in a table

Tags: 7

I've been searching to add filters in custom module based on MySQL table data.

I've created custom modules in which there are different list, now I want to add filters as it is in content, where content can be filtered based on status and type.

[custom filters http://www.imagesup.net/?di=8140773687515](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=8140773687515)

I've list as above where client details are listed, now I need to filer the list based on email address, phone number or his name. So I want a filter like below

[custom filters http://www.imagesup.net/?di=10140773699416](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=10140773699416)

I don't want to use Views.

Comment: can you please provide more info about what you want, come some of code here, tnx

Comment: @zhilevan updated the post

Comment: Something like this? http://knackforge.com/blog/karalmax/drupal-7-creating-drupal-style-tables-paging-sorting-and-filter

Comment: @FriOne, yes something like that, let me apply those filters.. I will get back soon